# Regular expressions replace string containing character @

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a function that should replace any string found in another string with the criteria that the string to replace starts with a `@` and it must be replaced only when it is an entire word.

But the code below does not work. The problem is with the character, `@`, because if I use another character at the start, for example, a X, it works. However even putting the `@` symbol between square brackets did not help.

```
public static string DB_Replace_Str(string st, string stFrom, string stTo)
{         
    stFrom = stFrom.Replace("@", "[@]");//this does not help
    string pattern = @"\b" + stFrom + @"\b";
    return Regex.Replace(st, pattern, stTo);
}
```

I post some example strings here:

- `st` = `"SELECT @table_Software.*,  @table_Teile.@Id as @TeilId FROM @table_Software LEFT JOIN @table_Teile ON @table_Software.@Id = @table_Teile.@Software_Id WHERE  @table_Software.@Id = 11"`
- `stFrom` = `"@table_Software"`
- `stTo` = `"tblSoftware"`

Comment: Can you show samples of the strings that you would be passing in the variables `st`, `stFrom` and `stTo` as its currently written it is very hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: From your description it doesn't sound like regex is the right thing to use, C# has plenty of (built in) ways to check what a string contains.

Comment: Are these the inputs ?            string st = "aaaa @bbb ccc ddd eee fff";
            string stFrom = "bbb";
            string stTo = "XXX";
            string ret = "aaaa XXX ccc ddd eee fff";
?

Comment: I am trying to post the strings but I get an error in stackoverflow: "only one additional @user etc...."
stackoverflow is also confused by the @ character

Comment: I don't want to spoil your research but there is a method that "Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string." Please read [ask] and try to take the time to format your questions.

Comment: @fsava: Is your expected output `SELECT tblSoftware.*,  @table_Teile.@Id as @TeilId FROM tblSoftware LEFT JOIN @table_Teile ON tblSoftware.@Id = @table_Teile.@Software_Id WHERE  tblSoftware.@Id = 11`?

Comment: @ stribizhev yes it is

Comment: the normal replace will replace also part of a longer word not only whole words, I need to replace only whole words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the non-word boundary first, and then a word boundary:

Details from [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> `\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".
>   `\B` is the negated version of `\b`. `\B` matches at every position where `\b` does not. Effectively, `\B` matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

```
public static string DB_Replace_Str(string st, string stFrom, string stTo)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("\\B{0}\\b", stFrom);
    return Regex.Replace(st, pattern, stTo);
}
```

Or even:

```
public static string DB_Replace_Str(string st, string stFrom, string stTo)
{
    return Regex.Replace(st, string.Format("\\B{0}\\b", Regex.Escape(stFrom)), stTo);
}
```

The output:

```
SELECT tblSoftware.*,  @table_Teile.@Id as @TeilId FROM tblSoftware LEFT JOIN @table_Teile ON tblSoftware.@Id = @table_Teile.@Software_Id WHERE  tblSoftware.@Id = 11
```

Comment: I think we can improve this a bit. Rather than creating a temp variable, we can use the `string.Format...` inside the `Regex.Replace`, and perhaps, we should also escape any metacharacters inside `stFrom` with `Regex.Escape` (although if there are any non-word characters at the end of `stFrom`, we won't get a match :()

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove word boundaries. Because I think there isn't a word boundary exists between the start and `[`

```
string pattern = @"(?<!\S)" + stFrom + @"(?!\S)";
```

or

```
string pattern = @"\B" + stFrom + @"\B";
```

Why it works when you put `X` at the start? Because there is a word boundary exists between `X` and `[`.

Comment: If I remove word boundaries then the function will replace the string also when it is not a complete word (e.g. part of a longer word)

Comment: I have updated the text of my answe rwith the sample strings.

Comment: mine won't work for you? What's your expected output?